# Python Threading to creates sample from environment

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

really sorry to ask , but i am a total noob at threading .... if someone can explain me the basics of this in python ....

I am trying to thread this to go faster , possibly with N tdqm progress bar ?
N Threads that fill a memory replay ..

```
def getSample(N):
    matrices = []
    labels = []

    while len(matrices)<N:
        action = 0
        game += 1
    

        playGame .....

    matrices = np.array(matrices)
    labels = np.array(labels) 


    return matrices,labels
```

Thanks a lot for reading me !

Comment: please properly format your code and provide a runnable example, a concrete question and what you have tried and why it does not work! I suggest you read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to accelerate your code execution using Python threading, then this will not do because although Python Threading allows multiple threads of execution, it does so on the same native thread and will continue using a single core. Python threading has its own use cases that you need to read about by looking into the various tutorials and examples online.

Multiprocessing could help you if you do not have dependencies between the different threads of executions except sending data to be processed to the various processes and gathering the results.

When large numerical data is being processed, your go-to is either numpy or Pandas, that if using vectorized operations, will greatly improve your performance and probably make use of all your cores as it executed natively out of the control of Python.

Comment: Hello, i am looking to use all my cores , as python at the moment is only using one of my cores of my processors ... and therefore 25/ of my cpu

Comment: @Mickael If you have a problem with the syntax, it's fixed. If you have a problem with the statement, please advise.